# getting req.params is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, parameters, routes, get, req

I need product id that's _id from my mongo document but when I consoled req.params.id it is showing undefined to my /shop page and I'm following mvc format

```
// get request://
router.get("/shop/:id",userController.shopPage)

//route://

 getProductPage: (req, res) => {
    try{
      let proId = req.params.id;
      console.log(proId)
      productHelpers
    .getProduct(proId)
    .then((products) => {
     
      res.render("user/view-product",{products}); })}
      catch(error){

      }

//get Product//

  getProduct: (proId) => {
    console.log(proId)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        db.products.find({_id:proId}).then((products) => {
          resolve(products);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  },
```

Comment: I'm sorry the one I provided was not my route that was shop page's route. the exact route is :                                                                                                                 router.get('/view-product/:id',userController.getProductPage)

Comment: @depperm this is my front end code:

Comment: is this angular? what are you entering in the url?